# Windows Phone 7 - How to get list of podcasts or media programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-7

For Windows Phone 7- Is it possible to list the media files (specifically podcasts) on the phone programmatically?  I've looked into the mediaplayerlauncher but that uses isolated storage.  I want to write a program which lists podcasts in the phone media hub in a simple manner with the newest ones listed first, any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can currently do this. The current API they have is very limited.